# ¿Por qué me sale este error? "TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str"

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo un proyecto donde debo crear un programa para registrar alumnos pero a la hora de utilizar el "str" me aparece ese error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    matricula=mu.pide_entero and mu.pide_cadena(1,5,"Escribe la matrícula del alumno: ")
nombre=mu.pide_cadena and mu.pide_cadena(1,15,"Escribe el nombre del alumno: ")
ap_paterno=mu.pide_cadena and mu.pide_cadena(1,15,"Escribe el apellido paterno del alumno: ")
ap_materno=mu.pide_cadena and mu.pide_cadena(1,15,"Escribe el apellido materno del alumno: ")
carrera=mu.pide_cadena and mu.pide_cadena(3,3,"Escribe la carrera del alumno:           ")
promedio=mu.pide_entero(0,100,"Escribe el promedio del alumno: ")

registro=str(matricula)+","+nombre+","+ap_paterno+","+ap_materno+","+carrera+","+promedio+"\n"
archivo=open("calificaciones.csv","a")
archivo.write(registro)
archivo.close()
```

Comment: Creo que el error esta en la variable promedio. Tambien deberia estar `str(promedio)` para que puedas concaternarlo.

Comment: Es mejor que pongas el código directamente en tu pregunta y no fotos para poder copiar y pgar el código y ayudarte mejor. Además, incluye todo el código relevante, brindando así un [mre].

Comment: @Pikksaar listo 

Comment: @nashvent era eso,  muchas gracias!!

Answer (score 1):

Como ya te habras dado cuenta, el error esta en intentar concatenar una cadena con un valor numérico. Eso no se puede hacer en Python

```
registro = nombre + nota # Es ilegal!
```

**Solución**

Cuando tengas que juntar textos y valores numéricos en una sola cadena, usa los formatos de edición.

Supongamos estos datos, que tienen cadenas, enteros y punto flotante, y los quiero juntar en una línea para grabarlo como CSV:

```
nombre="Juan"
apellido="Perez"
curso="CC101"
notas=7
promedio=5.7
```

En Python 3.8 y superior, puedo escribir un f-string (un cadena precedida de una letra 'f'). En la cadena encierras entre `{}` el nombre de la variable o una expresión Python válida:

```
registro=f"{nombre},{apellido},{curso},{notas},{promedio}"
```

Esto produce:

```
Juan,Perez,CC101,7,5.7
```

Python reemplaza cada `{expresion}` por el valor de la expresión encerrada. Puedes incluso escribir cosas como `{suma/numero}` y obtener el resultado de la operación:

```
numero=10
suma=459
registro=f"El promedio es {suma/numero}"
print(registro)
```

y obtener:

```
El promedio es 45.9
```

**Versiones anteriores**

En versiones anteriores puedes recurrir al formateo tradicional para obtener el mismo resultado:

```
registro="%s,%s,%s,%d,%.1f" % (nombre,apellido, curso, notas, promedio)
```

Es mucho más simple de escribir que andar concatenando cosas, haciendo conversiones, etc.